# Creating vertical and horizontal values for the median of the X and Y axis

Tags: axis, qlikview

I would like to display vertical and horizontal lines representing the median values of the X and Y values.  These median values are in the data.  This would divide the graph into quadrants.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scatter chart. And add reference lines into the chart to divide the chart into quadrants. reference line is in Presentation tab.